# Are the LFQ workflow arguments from DEP package all required or optional?

Tags: r, error-handling, package, arguments

I'm trying to run the LFQ workflow from the DEP package in R using my protein dataset but some arguments don't apply to my case:

```
# Run LFQ workflow of DEP package
data_results <- LFQ(comparison_table, expdesign, type = "all",
                    name = "description", alpha = 0.05, lfc = 1)
```

When running the code, I get errors like :

```
# Error: 'Protein.IDs' is not a column in 'comparison_table'.
# Error: 'Gene.names' is not a column in 'comparison_table'.
```

These errors indicate that these arguments are required for the code to run properly. However, when I tried the code using the example dataset provided in the package documentation, it worked without using some of the arguments:

```
data_results <- LFQ(data, experimental_design, fun = "MinProb", 
                    type = "control", control = "Ctrl", alpha = 0.05, lfc = 1)
```

worked with no errors although they didn't use some arguments like ids.

Here's my dataset comparison_table:

```
'data.frame':   4251 obs. of  41 variables:
 $ description: chr  "1433B" "1433E" "1433F" "1433G" ...
 $ S2.50      : num  0.1241 0.1535 0.0477 0.0412 0.041 ...
 $ S3.50      : num  0.1649 0.2283 0.0681 0.0821 0.0925 ...
 $ S4.50      : num  0.14 0.1455 0.0323 0.0501 0.0285 ...
 $ S5.50      : num  0.1028 0.1735 0.044 0.0366 0.1784 ...
 $ S6.50      : num  0.106 0.1268 0.0424 0.038 0.0463 ...
 $ S7.50      : num  0.0578 0.0906 0 0.0503 0.043 ...
 $ S8.50      : num  0.1112 0.1262 0.0229 0.0456 0.0713 ...
 $ S9.30      : num  0.275 0.1972 0.0494 0.0632 0.1748 ...
 $ S10.50     : num  0.2444 0.1801 0.04 0.0531 0 ...
 $ S11.30     : num  0.0911 0.1381 0.0195 0.0324 0 ...
 $ S13.50     : num  0.0557 0.1223 0.0186 0.0339 0.0706 ...
 $ S16.50     : num  0.1488 0.2271 0.0692 0.1448 0.0275 ...
 $ S18.50     : num  0.133 0.1941 0.0357 0.0582 0.2929 ...
 $ S21.50     : num  0.0452 0.1454 0.0264 0.0263 0.1271 ...
 $ S22.50     : num  0.1013 0.1303 0.0439 0.0471 0.0603 ...
 $ S23.50     : num  0.1362 0.2774 0.0492 0.0716 0.0826 ...
 $ S24.30     : num  0.0806 0.105 0.0242 0.0602 0.172 ...
 $ S25.50     : num  0.2112 0.1573 0.0482 0.107 0.0221 ...
 $ S26.50     : num  0.0747 0.1473 0.026 0.0453 0.0999 ...
 $ S27.50     : num  0.1742 0.1427 0.0394 0.0982 0 ...
 $ S28.50     : num  0.1813 0.1007 0.0275 0.0493 0.0763 ...
 $ S29.50     : num  0.137 0.2102 0.0156 0.0403 0.0432 ...
 $ S31.50     : num  0.1186 0.1456 0.0539 0.1181 0.1497 ...
 $ S33.30     : num  0.1494 0.2145 0.0382 0.0588 0.1861 ...
 $ S34.50     : num  0.1192 0.1255 0.0145 0.0648 0.2043 ...
 $ S35.30     : num  0.3148 0.0675 0.1399 0.0871 0.1041 ...
 $ S36.50     : num  0.0631 0.0468 0.0097 0.0483 0.0337 ...
 $ S37.50     : num  0.1911 0.1843 0.0303 0.0876 0.0181 ...
 $ S38.30     : num  0.1872 0.1354 0.0351 0.0505 0.1045 ...
 $ S40.50     : num  0.18 0.2015 0.0771 0.0832 0.1211 ...
 $ S41.50     : num  0.1595 0.1871 0.0156 0.0717 0.0807 ...
 $ S42.30     : num  0.0743 0.1569 0.0418 0.0416 0.0323 ...
 $ S44.50     : num  0.0888 0.156 0.0571 0.0663 0 ...
 $ S45.50     : num  0.117 0.1437 0.0355 0.0283 0.0176 ...
 $ S46.50     : num  0.2356 0.1623 0.0294 0.0461 0 ...
 $ S48.50     : num  0.0876 0.1655 0.0245 0.0837 0 ...
 $ S49.50     : num  0.1308 0.1452 0.0425 0.0358 0 ...
 $ S50.50     : num  0.1036 0.1766 0.0449 0.0447 0.1131 ...
 $ S51.50     : num  0.2043 0.1906 0.0201 0.0767 0.0565 ...
 $ S52.50     : num  0.2043 0.1183 0 0.0661 0 ...
```

The description column has the proteins/gene names and all other columns are samples.

Here are the LFQ workflow arguments:

-proteins
Data.frame, The data object.

-expdesign
Data.frame, The experimental design object.

-fun
"man", "bpca", "knn", "QRILC", "MLE", "MinDet", "MinProb", "min", "zero", "mixed" or "nbavg", Function used for data imputation based on manual_impute and impute.

-type
'all', 'control' or 'manual', The type of contrasts that will be generated.

-control
Character(1), The sample name to which the contrasts are generated (the control sample would be most appropriate).

-test
Character, The contrasts that will be tested if type = "manual". These should be formatted as "SampleA_vs_SampleB" or c("SampleA_vs_SampleC", "SampleB_vs_SampleC").

-filter
Character, Name(s) of the column(s) to be filtered on.

-name
Character(1), Name of the column representing gene names.

-ids
'Character(1), Name of the column representing protein IDs.

-alpha
Numeric(1), sets the false discovery rate threshold.

-lfc
Numeric(1), sets the log fold change threshold.

I tried the code for my dataset and I was expecting it to work just like the example they provided in the package documentation but it didn't as described above.

Comment: Please run `dput(comparison_table)` and copy the result into your question. Without seeing your data it's difficult to diagnose your issue.

Comment: Hi Leroy, I provided information about my dataset. I hope it's enough to diagnose my issue. Thanks!